# Rcloud group management

Tags: rcloud

Have below two questions regarding how RCloud manages users and groups:

1. When users are initially provisioned to RCloud, is there a default group for all new users?
2. After creating a new group in RCloud, can I restrict only that group have access to my notebooks?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I missed your question for so long!

1. No, there is no default notebook permissions group.
2. There is no automatic way to assign your notebooks to a group.

As I'm sure you know, to assign a notebook to a group, click the `i` circle information icon next to the notebook, then click the link indicating the group it's currently in, and select the notebook group in the resulting dialog.

RCloud has always been about sharing techniques with others, so by default we want notebooks to be shared and searchable. However, we may consider a feature like this in the future.

Most likely it will be as an extension. I am not sure if the APIs exist to write such an extension today. (E.g. a hook when new notebooks are created.)

It may be possible to write a notebook today that moves all of your notebooks to a group.